# How to create sliding up panel with icon in flutter?

Tags: flutter, sliding

How to create bottom sliding up panel like that?[image]

I added plugin sliding up panel plugin for flutter. Here is the following code

```
collapsed:Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: radius
            ),
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5,right: 5),
                child:Container(
                  height: 90,
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(//first container 
                          height: 20,
                          width: 60,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5,top: 5),
                            child:RaisedButton(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                onPressed: (){},
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
                            ) ,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(//second container
                          height: 60,
                          child: ListTile(
                            onTap: (){},
                            title: Text('Cart: ',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                            trailing: Text("Total( "+" :sum)"),
                          ),
                        )
                      ]
                  ),
                )
            )
        ),
```

The result is [image]

So how can move first container like first image?

Comment: What is your question about? Where do you want to move your first container? Please specify

Answer (score 0):

Use the library slide_up_panel:

https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel

Answer (score 0):

I change the `SlidingUpPanel` color to transparent and only use Background color white on the Wanted Header. Maybe you should fix the box shadow to your preference, and I think you should reduce the padding and the icon height a bit.

```
SlidingUpPanel(
      minHeight: 90,
      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
      backdropEnabled: true,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
        top: Radius.circular(20),
      ),
      color: Colors.transparent,
      collapsed: Container(
        child: Container(
          height: 90,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  //first container
                  height: 20,
                  width: 60,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {},
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  //second container
                  height: 60,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                      top: Radius.circular(20),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () {},
                    title: Text(
                      'Cart: ',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    trailing: Text("Total( " + " :sum)"),
                  ),
                )
              ]),
        ),
      ),
);
```